# HttpContext.Request.Url returning IP Address (Random)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, networking, application-pool

I have hosted an MVC web application in IIS7.5. The application is multilingual. For example:

www.myapp.com

www.myapp.ca

www.myapp.mx

www.myapp.co.in

fr.myapp.com

To generate metadata (URL in my case), I am using the below code.

```
 var url = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
```

But randomly the below code is generating, IP Address instead of URL.

Any thoughts for this behavior?

Comment: What happens if you browse to the site using an IP address instead of a DNS name?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - It is giving IP Address only

Comment: That's because the IP address is all that was in the URL. It's not going to magically change an IP address into a DNS name. Most likely, the failures you're getting are from someone (or some bot) making requests using the IP address.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Can you help me with the second issue, which I just updated. I will check with the 1st issue in smart glass and get back

Comment: How in the world would I know why your meta tag says whatever it says? I'm not psychic! You don't even say which meta tag, nor do you show us what it looks like. Finally, it's a separate question, so please as a separate question, and perhaps include a link to this one.